# SQL cursor instead of union for select statements

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, union-all, sql-server-2017

I have a SQL Server procedure that is in need of an update. Currently, it has 3 INPUT parameters (program IDs), and uses those parameters to run 3 SELECT statements joined by a UNION ALL. Now the requirements have changed to where it can be 2 or 3 INPUT parameters passed into it.

Creating another procedure, and calling either procedure from my ASP.Net site based on a IF condition is simply a terrible idea for me. Instead I would like to be able to condense the stored procedure to allow for a variable amount of INPUT parameters and run the same select statement without having to use a UNION ALL.

Currently it is something like this:

```
SELECT name, startdate, enddate FROM xyztable WHERE x1 = id1
UNION ALL
SELECT name, startdate, enddate FROM xyztable WHERE x1 = id2
UNION ALL
SELECT name, startdate, enddate FROM xyztable WHERE x1 = id3
```

Would a cursor be the ideal way to do this instead? (kind of confused on how they work)

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following as well as using `IN (xxx, xxx, xxx)`, however, it is tripling every record. Will I have to do a major rework with the code?

```
SELECT 
    WS.ProgramID,
    WS.ItemID,
    WS.Day,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, WS.Day - 1, WE.eventstartdate))
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Sun'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Mon'
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Tue'
       WHEN 4 THEN 'Wed'
       WHEN 5 THEN 'Thu'
       WHEN 6 THEN 'Fri'
       WHEN 7 THEN 'Sat'
       ELSE 'N/A'
    END + ' '
        + CONVERT(CHAR(12), DATEADD(DAY, WS.Day - 1, WE.eventstartdate), 101) AS Date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(TIME, SUBSTRING(WS.TimeSlot, 0, 6)), 100) AS 'Begin TIME',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(TIME, SUBSTRING(WS.TimeSlot, 7, 6)), 100) AS 'End TIME',
    WS.TimeSlot,
    WS.SlotType,
    WSSTC.Description AS SlotTypeDescription,
    WS.SlotInfo,
    WSSIC.Description AS SlotInfoDescription,
    ISNULL(WSI.TalkID, 0) AS TalkID,
    LEFT(WPI.FirstName, 10) + ' ' + LEFT(WPI.LastName, 10) + ' ('
           + LEFT(WEA.institution, 10) + ')' + ' - '
           + LEFT(WSI.Title, 10) + '...' + RIGHT(WSI.Title, 10) AS Talk,
    WPI.FirstName,
    WPI.LastName,
    WEA.institution,
    WSI.AuthorLine,
    WSI.Title,
    LEFT(WSI.Abstract, 1) AS Abstract,
    WS.Location,
    WS.Addendum,
    WE.EventName
FROM   
    dbo.WebSpeakerInfo WSI
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.WebPersonalInfo WPI ON WSI.UserID = WPI.UserID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.webeventaffiliation WEA ON WPI.UserID = WEA.userid
                                AND (WEA.eventid = 3515 OR wea.eventid = 3516 OR WEA.eventid = 3471)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.WebScheduleSlotTypeCodes WSSTC
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.WebSchedules WS ON WSSTC.SlotType = WS.SlotType 
    ON WSI.TalkID = WS.TalkID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.WebScheduleSlotInfoCodes WSSIC ON WS.SlotInfo = WSSIC.SlotInfo
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.WebEvents WE ON (WE.eventid = 3515 OR we.eventid = 3516 OR WE.eventid = 3471)
WHERE  
    (WS.ProgramID = 3515 OR ws.ProgramID = 3516 OR ws.ProgramID = 3471)
    AND WS.SlotType <> 6
```

Comment: Why was my question voted down?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a series of equality conditions with `or`s between them (or an `in` condition, which is just a shorthand for them). Since `null` can never be equal to a value, and `null`s you pass for the second and third id would just be ignored:

```
SELECT name, startdate, enddate FROM xyztable WHERE x1 IN (id1, id2, id3)
```

Comment: HAHA, I apologize to laugh, but it your suggestion works I am going to kick myself in the butt. I will try that and let you know. How simple...

Comment: unfortunately it triplicated all of the records